# How to emulate at once 10 successive clicks from console using JS for infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, mouseevent, infinite-scroll

To fetch more data on an already loaded page (infinite scrolling), I have to click on `more`.

---

From the browser console, I can successfully simulate such an user action by running:

```
eventFire(document.querySelector('.more'),'click');
```

using the following snippet found somewhere here on S.O.:

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}
```

---

#### Question

I need to find a pure javascript (no library) way to be able to run **only once** from the console a snippet emulating a *10 successive clicks* on `more`.

---

#### What I've tried so far

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  eventFire(document.querySelector('.more'),'click');
}
```

It just loads one batch of records corresponding only to one click and basta.

Comment: If the results are retrieved through ajax, as they most likely are, I would imaging you would have to wait between the clicks until data has been loaded. Try adding a timeout between the clicks.

Comment: Yes indeed, it uses some ajax under the hood. So you mean that I have to sync the mouse event with the completion of the current request otherwise the event queue will be wiped?

Comment: I can't really tell you how the site works, since I do not know. I believe however the the event queue is not wiped, but since the link is clicked 10 times "instantly", and it since the latest result was "result 10" for instance, it still only retrieves until "result 20". Either it retrieves the same result (result 11 through 20) 10 times, or it ignores multiple clicks requesting the same resources.

Comment: Any hint for the timeout duration?

Comment: However long it seems to take the results to load when clicking it. You can check your network tab in the developer options and see the time a request uses, and then make a decision based on that. I would imagine anywhere from 500ms to a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your all inputs.